# Edit SQL Requests in Transit

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am trying to update a legacy system's sql solution to use the cloud.

The solution today involves a customer Windows SQL server installed onsite, then various machines are configured to connect to that IP Address / Port / Server Name. When they do connect the machines will set up any tables that are missing and regularly send their data. Data rates are low for an individual machine. Roughly one write request ever 10 seconds (it varies a lot), no more than 2-3k of information on each write request.

Moving this to the cloud is tricky mostly because each of the machines do not have a unique identifier. The good news is that we have the legacy machines connected to a IOT Gateway (Just think RPI) that knows a unique machineId. Furthermore the IOTG is a full fledge computer but not too powerful of one, and its Disk is an SD card. 
[New and Old Network Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iunXa.png)
So far I have had a few things fall on their face.

1) Setting the Machine to think the DB's IP/Port is that of the IOT Gateway. Setting up an Express server on the IOTG, listening, then injecting the unique id into the queries that I'd proxy up to the cloud. I may have had a bug, but for some reason I couldn't even see the requests coming in on the port. Even if I could I'd still have to figure out how to decode them. Shouldn't I at least be able to see these requests coming in?

2) Started looking into SQLite. The idea being to have SQLite listen on the port as an actual DB then have a process in the IOTG query data out of SQLite, append a unique ID, and then send it to the cloud. Unfortunately SQLite does not listen on a port.

I am starting to looking at just installing a whole SQL server on the device, but I'd really like to avoid that. I'm pretty sure its fairly large and writing to disk is not advisable for a small embedded system like I'm running.

Generally my questions boil down to:

1) Should I be able to see SQL Queries in an express server?

2) Should I be using a different tech? I failed to find a different more sql specific proxy.

3) Am I correct to think that the SQLite path is dead? Even if I could find a way to attach it to a port there is still not going to be any sort of response from SQLite when the clients try to make a connection.

4) Am I wrong to fear the local server? Diving into some documentation for making express work with DBs gets me to here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/node/ubuntu/ which suggests 4GB of memory, we're working on 0.5GB.

Any other thoughts on how to approach this would be great.

Comment: What is your question here? The only quesrtion I see is *"Shouldn't I at least be able to see these requests coming in?"* which I doubt is your actual question here.

Comment: I suppose it is a bit open ended / I have many. Will update.

Comment: SQL Server and SQLite (not to be confused with SQL Express, which is a version of SQL Server) are entirely different database engines, and while *most* SQL is standard, it's the parts that aren't that will trip you up. Unless your application is written in a generic way, it's improbable that you'd be able to port it from one to the other without rewrites (and if you're doing that, you may as well make it not use SQL). Aside from this, SQLite runs in-process and has no network capability (that's a feature, not a bug), so you'd still need another application to forward the requests.

Comment: For proxying TDS (the protocol SQL Server speaks), a generic TCP/IP proxy would do if you're always connecting to the same server. You could not inject a machine ID in this way, but you could pass this explicitly from the application with `sp_set_session_context`, which the server can access with `SESSION_CONTEXT()`, or in the `Application Name` property in the session string, which it can access with `APP_NAME()`.

Comment: Jeroen, I do currently plan to connect to the same server every time. Then if I can set the Application Name within my proxy I could have a default value of a column be "APP_NAME()" then I'd have a bunch of different clients all inserting their own data with a unique Id! That sounds like a really clever solution. I only have one question, how do I set the app name? I Think this means I need to decode one packet and add a query that does sp_set_session_context? Diving into this further now, thanks again!

Comment: I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf proxies that "speak" TDS natively. Any solution where you want to modify the connection string or insert requests that doesn't involve changing the client would have to be custom developed. The TDS protocol is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec), but it's not exactly trivial. My recommendation would be to make the connection string configurable in your application (if it's not already) and find a way to set it there as part of having the application deployed.